# text search of value with "." in searched value

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of 2 million documents with 20 fields. A couple of the fields have <strike>"-" and</strike> "." in then and a unique filename field.

## Update

**I have converted the "-" to "_" and the problem still exists. It appears that the "." is causing most of the issues. I think the indexer splits on the dot so the filename is indexed and the extension is indexed but not the whole filename + extension.**

## End of update

Here is a sample of the documents I have. (note: if you do the test with this sample it will return quick but on 2 million documents the result speed changes)

```
{ 
    "FileName" : "NA2148-958-041114.PDF",
    "Customer" : "customer-958"
},
{ 
    "FileName" : "NA2149-958-041116.PDF",
    "Customer" : "customer-958"
},
{ 
    "FileName" : "NA2149-959-041118.PDF",
    "Customer" : "customer-959"
}
```

I have created the following full text search on the collection.

> db.test.createIndex( {"$**": "text"})

If I do a full search for the full filename it takes takes upto 65 secs to return the single document.

> db.test.find({$text: {$search: "\"NA2148-958-041114.PDF\""}})

If I do an explain()

> db.test.find({$text: {$search: "\"NA2148-958-041114.PDF\""}}).explain()

```
"parsedTextQuery" : {
                "terms" : [ 
                    "041114", 
                    "958", 
                    "na2148", 
                    "pdf"
                ],
                "negatedTerms" : [],
                "phrases" : [ 
                    "NA2148-958-041114.PDF"
                ],
                "negatedPhrases" : []
            }
```

I was expecting the terms in the explain to be the same as the phrases and search the index with that value.

If I do the below search it returns the document in about 15 secs.

> db.test.find({$text: {$search: "NA2148-958-041114.PDF"}}).explain()   *** (without ") **)

```
{
    "terms" : [ 
        "041114", 
        "958", 
        "na2148", 
        "pdf"
    ],
    "negatedTerms" : [],
    "phrases" : [],
    "negatedPhrases" : []
}
```

If I do the below search it returns the document in under 1 sec.

> db.test.find({$text: {$search: "041114"}})

```
{
    "terms" : [ 
        "041114"
    ],
    "negatedTerms" : [],
    "phrases" : [],
    "negatedPhrases" : []
}
```

I suspect the indexing step is splitting up the value and therefore there is no index for the whole file name only the chunks.

Is there a way either to get the search to use the phrase only and not tokernize it when surrounded by "" or get the indexing steps to not tokenize on the "-" or "." in the filename?

Note: I have read that indexing with $default_language: "none" will use simple tokernizer but that did not change the outcome.

Any help or direction on this topic would be great.

---

Here is the results when adding in "\" in front of the "-" No different in the explain() or the speed.

> db.text.find({$text: {$search: "\"NA2148\-958\-041114\.PDF\""}}).explain()

```
{
    "terms" : [ 
        "041114", 
        "958", 
        "na2148", 
        "pdf"
    ],
    "negatedTerms" : [],
    "phrases" : [ 
        "NA2148-958-041114.PDF"
    ],
    "negatedPhrases" : []
}
```

Comment: Have you tried '\' escaping the '-' characters in your query? It looks like they are currently being interpreted as query delimiters, but I think you want the actual '-' characters.

Comment: Yes I have tried that and it does not appear to make any difference. I did find this info. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters

Comment: For tokenization, version 3 text index uses the delimiters categorized under Dash, Hyphen, Pattern_Syntax, Quotation_Mark, Terminal_Punctuation, and White_Space