# How to create a proper text index in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing

I have a collection of 1.5 million docs with a field name `SOURCEREFERENCE`. The field value is in the below format:

```
/abc/xyz/ABCDE/BascIT/QEYEO02/processing/20191111-1614040317082000100-ff451057-180f-40b8-bcfb-0676aadff867-document.inp##1
```

I have created a text index, and the query:

```
db.stores.createIndex( { SOURCEREFERENCE: "text" } )

db.stores.find( { $text: { $search: "\"20191111-1614040317082000100-ff451057-180f-40b8-bcfb-0676aadff867-document\"" } } )
```

Its doing an index scan but when I see the explain plan i can see its examining nearly 1.5 million keys and documents to fetch 1 record.

Comment: In general, text indexes entries are created based on whitespace and hyphens as delimiters in the text field. A text field value like "alfa beta-xyz" will create three index entries "alfa", "beta" and "xyz" (on which you can search by index). So searching with `db.coll.find( { $text: { $search: "alfa xyz" } } )` will use the index properly. See this document on [text index delimiters](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#tokenization-delimiters).

Comment: If you run an `explain()` on the query you can see that the index on the text "20191111-1614040317082000100-ff451057-180f-40b8-bcfb-0676aadff867-document" has created 8 entries (as it has 8 tokens based delimited by hyphens).

Comment: Thanks prasad_.  Is there any way I can get the search result faster instead of scanning all the documents in the collection ?

Comment: You can also see this on how a hyphen affects a query: [negations in text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#negations).

Comment: Here is some info about how the hyphens are treated in the text search: [text search of value with “.” in searched value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37460583/text-search-of-value-with-in-searched-value).